# Goals Missed Due To delay In A Major Project

Tags: communication, performance-reviews, review

In preparation for my performance review, I realized that one of my goals became unattainable. I was responsible for an increase in webpage visits; however, a campaign that was designed to help with this objective was delayed. Therefore, the increase in web visits didn't happen. How should I frame my failure to meet this goal in my written performance review?

Comment: Could you clarify if you were (even partially) responsible for the delay of the campaign? You wrote: _" I was responsible for an increase in webpage visits"_  Did you hire a marketing firm to do the campaign and they just couldn't deliver on time?

Comment: If you weren't responsible for the campaing describe all other steps you took to achieve your goal. If your only way to achieve that goal was to relay on someone else work why it was your goal?

Answer (score 7):

**Just be honest.** It's generally the best policy after all!

Something along the lines of:

> One of my goals was to increase web page visits, however the campaign that was designed to help with this objective was delayed and therefore I was not able to complete that goal this time around.

Be sure to discuss how you plan to achieve that goal going forward and what delayed the project (without throwing anyone under the bus as that is not helpful to anyone).

Answer (score 4):

> *How should I frame my failure to meet this goal in my written performance review?*

**Don't "frame" it as anything, present the facts**.

You missed a target, be truthful about it, and show your

- ***Efforts:*** You worked towards achieving it but could not get it.
- ***Planning:*** You have a plan forward to make up for the lack of achievement of this time.

There key things in general about performance review to keep in mind:

- **Never, ever blame others** : Whatever be the reason, do not speak ill about others (colleagues, juniors, contractors - anyone). Even if the performance (or lack of it) is because some deadlock from someone else - do not blame them, put that incident as an unfortunate one and take a commitment for better planning next time.
- **Accept responsibilities (for both good and bad):** Express you contribution to the good work and accomplishments, and also accept the shortcomings without trying to cover them or providing "excuses". No one is perfect - but the ones who knows the shortcomings and willing to accept them are one step closer to perfection that others.
- **Have a plan forward to improve:** Always, always plan forward for the future. Better planning help us achieve more with quality, so we have time for some more planning. Take your lessons learnt and utilize them to build a better plan.

Comment: Also, prepare some better goals for yourself (that don't have so many dependencies on others)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Agreed, added.

Comment: _Dear Downvoter, along with the downvote, if you can leave a comment mentioning what is not useful about the answer, and how it can possibly be improved, it'll be helpful. Thanks._